# Cannot map @ConfigurationProperties bean to @Component bean

Tags: java, spring

Instance for configuration class is created correctly but not mapped in `@Component` class correctly, showing up as `null`. Why is `@Component` class to be annotated since `@Autowired` does not seem to work at all? Thank you.

```
@Configuration    
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="wmi2017")    
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:wmi2017.properties",  ignoreResourceNotFound = false)

public class Wmi2017Properties {
}
```

--> Without `@Configuration`, this does not work

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties(Wmi2017Properties.class)
public class WmiCollection {

    @Autowired
    private Wmi2017Properties wmiProps;
```

`@Autowired` does not work and `wmiPros` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties(Wmi2017Properties.class)
public class WmiCollection {

    //@Autowired
    private Wmi2017Properties wmiProps;

public WmiCollection (Wmi2017Properties wmiProps){

this.wmiProps = wmiProps;
}
```